# Working but hidden/missing entities

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have several modules in my zf2 application, they all have their own entities and all on the same connection.

A little diagram to explain the situation :

```
-Module 1
    -Entity A
    -Entity B
-Module 2
    -Entity C
    -Entity B
(all on the same database connection)
```

The problem is all the entities are working, i can fetch, update them, etc. but some are "invisible". I have some cross-module relations and they are working fine too.

For exemple, all entities from module 2 does not appear when I use the `php public/index.php orm:info` command nor in the Zend Developer Toolbar.

When I edit an entity, I have to manually update the database as `php public/index.php orm:schema-tool:update` says `Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.`

The entities can be fetched, they are just not "seen" by the ZDT nor the terminal, I don't know what I did wrong.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is often caused when the path to the entities has not been [declared in your config](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule#entities-settings):

```
<?php
    return array(
        'doctrine' => array(
            'driver' => array(
                // defines an annotation driver with two paths, and names it `my_annotation_driver`
                'my_annotation_driver' => array(
                    'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                    'cache' => 'array',
                    'paths' => array(
                        'path/to/my/entities',
                        'another/path'
                    ),
                ),

                // default metadata driver, aggregates all other drivers into a single one.
                // Override `orm_default` only if you know what you're doing
                'orm_default' => array(
                    'drivers' => array(
                        // register `my_annotation_driver` for any entity under namespace `My\Namespace`
                        'My\Namespace' => 'my_annotation_driver'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: I changed my quivalent of `my_annotation_driver` (from `bm_entity` to `application_entity`) and it worked, Maybe it was a conflict with an other module